# Unable to close the bottom banner in the dev Stack Overflow page

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, dev.so

In the [Dev Stack Overflow](https://dev.stackoverflow.com) page, unable to close the bottom banner. When click on the close (X) button it is not responding. I have verified in the recent Chrome and Firefox browsers.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Bottom banner]

Comment: Repro'ed Win 10 Chrome 68.0.3440.84

Comment: Reproduced in `Mozilla Firefox 58.0.` & `Google Chrome 64.0` OS `linux`

Comment: Reproducible on Firefox Nightly 63.0a1. Upon debugging, it seems that pressing that button calls `initGdprBanner` which issues an AJAX POST request to set an HTTP only cookie. It requests `url: "/accounts/accept-gdpr-consent-banner"` and expects `dataType: "json"`. However, the response is not JSON; it appears to be just the current page as HTML.

Comment: I assume you need to be logged in for this to work, has anyone done this while being authenticated?

Comment: Reproducible on MS Edge 40.15063.674.0

Comment: @Xufox it's not exactly the current page that is returned, it's a redirect to the login page for the URL that is posted to: `https://dev.stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=beta&returnurl=%2faccounts%2faccept-gdpr-consent-banner`. This bug is likely because of configuration specific to the Dev site and thus unrelated to the production site, so I'll vote to close this as off-topic.