# "How are we doing!?" is haunting me

Tags: discussion, support, survey

> [image]

This follows me everywhere. Closing the banner (clicking the x) simply doesn't help. It shows up again when visiting different sections/routes of the website!

Homepage with closed banner:

> [image]

How do I hide it permanently?

Comment: Really? There's *another* survey banner with broken functionality? You'd think they'd fix the system the first times

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl maybe it slipped the code review and the testing.

Comment: Well, did you take the survey? Did you? Did you? Huh? If not, why not? Why do you think you're entitled to ignore it in the first place? ...would you like to take our short survey on these questions?

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl there is just too much going on, testing is not a priority...

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC Well **we** are the testers. Better get paid for the same!

Comment: @boop_the_snoot why pay someone when you can get it for free

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC Tbf, this exact bug has popped up a couple times in the past on the exact same type of banner. It's not about testing as much as creating a standard system to prevent this from happening every time a new banner is pushed.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl Agreed. Obviously it was not fixed properly.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl Where at? There's been a couple survey banner bugs, but this one's unrelated to them as far as I can tell.

Comment: @AdamLear Good question. I remember a couple meta posts about undismissable banners, and now that I come to think of it, I actually don't remember if it was a survey banner or a banner for something else. Finding those is gonna be hard, because I don't remember roughly when they were posted, nor the context, so I can't find search terms or manually dig it up by date range. They were fixed IIRC.

Comment: @AdamLear well, there were a lot fewer "banner" questions than I expected. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388936/no-i-dont-want-to-take-your-survey is one, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372105/6296561 is related and there's an older one (from '17). I still remember a second one with the same type of banner, but given the one I linked first was closed as a dupe (and likely after I first saw it), it might've shifted the count. Dunno though, that's all I could find.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl Cool, thanks for looking! I'm pretty sure I fixed https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388936/no-i-dont-want-to-take-your-survey, and I honestly have zero interest in bug reports for our dev tier unless they have to do with actually getting access to a dev tier site. :) We're keeping a close eye on survey-related bug reports... hopefully this was just a one-off and not something systemic.

Comment: Exactly one year later, I believe this is fixed. [There was a bug in the survey code triggered by the collapsed left nav user preference.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402000/860000)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Huh, that is hella weird. There's nothing special about the homepage vs other locations, so once the banner is dismissed, it *should* be hidden everywhere.

But more interestingly... I dug around a bit and as far as I can tell, you ended up in a strange state. We have a record of a survey invite cached in Redis, but absolutely nothing in the DB, and I don't see any relevant exceptions that'd explain what possibly happened with that. So, that's fun.

The good news, such as it is, is that we do automatically expire these banners after 3 days, so assuming no other shenanigans, you should hopefully not see the banner anymore by the time I'm writing this.

I'll do my best to investigate further and try to reproduce your case. It's certainly not our intent to annoy anyone with these invites.

Comment: I can confirm the banner is gone now.

Comment: This is still going on. Again.

Comment: @AdamLear - With all due respect, this is not an answer.  You said you'd investigate and never followed up and this bug still exists.  This isn't bad as a comment but I'm a bit frustrated because now my [new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395901/how-are-we-doing-take-our-short-survey-how-are-we-doing-take-our-short-survey) has been closed citing this as an answer, which seems silly because nothing is offered here which actually solves the problem.

Comment: @billynoah My bad on not coming back to update the answer here. Long story short, I found a few bugs and fixed them a while back - mostly around folks getting invited to more than one survey or cache keys not expiring at the right time. As far as I know... the banners *should* be dismissing correctly now, though it's evidently not happening. I know we need to dig more but there hasn't been time. I wish I could have an ETA here, but the best I can honestly say at the moment is that I'll dig up the Trello card we have for tracking this and try to pick it back up sometime soon.

Comment: @AdamLear This still needs attention. The survey site knows I have taken the survey, but SO does not remember that. Is there a cookie we could manually set to prevent the banner from appearing?

Comment: Its happening for me, too.

Comment: This is happening for me too now. I even took the survey and it still keeps coming back. The AJAX request to the `/dismiss` endpoint goes through but on a refresh it’s back (not on the question list though). – And no, it’s **not** good news that it will expire after three days. I really don’t want this to stick around for three days.

Answer (score 6):

Try blocking the element with a ad-blocker like [ublock-origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock#installation).

Comment: extensions are a no-no on my work computer. Anyways it's gone now, maybe because of the 3 days threshold as mentioned by @Adam in his answer