# Getting prompt to take survey, but clicking to take it results in error

Tags: bug, survey

When I refresh the Stack Overflow interace, I see an invitation to participate in a survey:

[image]

When I click on "Take our short survey, I get a message that I've either completed the survey already, or that my session has expired:

[image]

I tried five times, always the same result.

Comment: Duplicate? [“How are we doing!?” is haunting me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390298/1364007)

Comment: @WaiHaLee Doesn't appear to be, as that does not report an error...

Comment: @WaiHaLee that's just a failure to dismiss - this is an issue with the survey itself

Comment: I am not 100% sure if this is something on the Qualtrics side (and I don't have access to it, so can't check) or ours, but I did find another bug on our end that seems unrelated, but not so much that I'd bet on it. I put a potential workaround in place for your account. Would you mind trying again and let me know if it lets you through that time? Thanks!

Comment: @AdamLear Thank you for responding. Same behavior, I'm afraid...

Comment: @AdamLear Update: The behavior I was seeing, for almost 24 hours, was on my iPad. I just now logged in a Windows machine and was able to take the survey. Don't know if something was fixed, or if it's an issue with iPad/Safari...

Comment: @CindyMeister Did you fill out the survey back in July? And if so, was that also on your iPad?

Comment: @AdamLear I did take an earlier survey, but I can't swear that it was in July :-) Nor can I be absolutely sure I took it on the iPad. If I *had* to say, I'd say not, that I took it on my main machine. But I simply don't remember - not important enough in my life to move from short- to long-term memory. Additional info: I've still been seeing the blue bar across the top of my SO pages - on both machines - until "now", even though I'd taken the survey. It was there for the last few days, but gone when I came back now (6 hrs since last I looked). This just for any data you're collecting :-)